# Intersection automaton of two automata

Tags: proof-verification, computer-science, automata

I need to build the intersection automaton of these two automata

[image]

**My attempt:**

[image]

> My attempt is correct?

Comment: Seems to be OK.

Comment: @zoli Ok thank's

Comment: It's fine, except that you need to identify the accepting states

Comment: @KlausDraeger Yes, you are right